# Ollydbg Plugin Development

Tags: ollydbg, plugin, ollyscript

I wanted to write a simple Ollydbg plugin that shows me, for example, a simple message like hello world. in further, I wanted to learn how can I write a complex plugin to hook a function and to modify its parameters and so on. Is there any manual for that job?

Comment: Did you try the manual that comes with OllyDbg?

Comment: No, where can I find it?

Comment: I did a conversion to chm here: https://github.com/x64dbg/OllyDbg/blob/master/OllyDbg/OllyDbg%20Plugins%20Reference.chm